# Update data many-to-many in typeorm express

Tags: javascript, express, many-to-many, typeorm, relation

i tried both **.save** and **.update** but it cause an error, --in the case of **.save** it return error: *the value of a duplicate key breaks the unique constraint* --in **.update** case it return error: *the "userId" column of the "user" relation does not exist*

note: i have 2 tables role and user and the association user_role

```
 //Many-to-many relation with user
  @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.roles)
  users: User[];



//Many-to-many relation with role
  @ManyToMany((type) => Role, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable({
    name: "users_roles",
    joinColumn: { name: "userId", referencedColumnName: "id" },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: "roleId" }
  })
  roles: Role[];
```

the source code is :
/* exemple of data
entity2 = {
username: 'user8',
password: 'user8',
firstname: 'test',
lastname: 'tt',
email: 'user8@gmail.com',
company: 18,
roles: [ { id: 62 }, { id: 63 } ]
} */

```
  let entity = await this.userRepository.create(data.payload);

            let entity2 = { ...entity, roles: data.payload.selectedRoles }
    
 
            const user = await this.userRepository.save(entity2);
          /*const user = await this.userRepository.update(id, entity2);*/

            //todo we need to serialize the user
            // return only what we need like username , email, ...etc not password!!!!
            return { success: true, user: SanitizeUser(user) };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did findone then .save, 1st get the data to update using data= this.userRepository.findOne(id) then you can apply userRepository.save(data) to this data. for example :

```
const userUpdated = await this.userRepository.findOne(id)
      let dataUpdated = {
        ...userUpdated,
        username: data.payload.username,
        firstname: data.payload.firstname,
        lastname: data.payload.lastname,
        email: data.payload.email,
        company: data.payload.selectedCompany,
        roles: data.payload.selectedRoles
      }

      const user = await this.userRepository.save(dataUpdated);
```